# I want to sort multidimensional array according to the date wise and also count the Number of data occurance in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hi everyone I am a new newbie in php. I tried so many things to do this but i cant get the desired output. 
This is my array i Want to to sort the array and count the number of month in the array and also count the data occurrence in the array after push all the data to new array according to the months,no. of data count,Key pairs.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/07/23 06:20
            [comp_status] => Lead
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/07/23 06:20
            [comp_status] => Lead
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/07/23 06:20
            [comp_status] => Opportunity
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/07/24 06:20
            [comp_status] => Conversion
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/07/24 06:20
            [comp_status] => Lead
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/08/24 06:20
            [comp_status] => Opportunity
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/08/24 06:20
            [comp_status] => Conversion
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/07/25 06:20
            [comp_status] => Lead
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/06/25 06:20
            [comp_status] => Opportunity
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/08/25 06:20
            [comp_status] => Conversion
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [comp_date] => 2015/08/25 06:20
            [comp_status] => Lead
        )
)
```

This is my actual array.
I had tired this

```
function yearWiseCalculation(){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT comp_date,comp_status FROM `hr_companies` WHERE  year(comp_date)=year(curdate())");
$arr =[];
while ($total = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    array_push($arr,$total);
    $ex = explode(" ", $total['comp_date']);
    $ex = explode(" ", $ex[0]);
    $k = explode("/", $ex[0]);
    $time[]=strtotime($ex[0]);
    $month[]=date("F",$time[0]);
}
```

I want Output in This Form are given Below

```
 Array(
       [0] => Array
        (
            [comp_month] => july
            [lead] => 4
            [opportunity] => 1
            [conversion] => 1
        )
      [1] => Array
        (
            [comp_month] => August
            [lead] => 1
            [opportunity] => 1
            [conversion] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: I tried first sort the data according to the date after that i fetch the months from the date while explode the first elements of array and push it into new array but i unable to count the number of months occurrence in an array and i cant separate them and also not able to count the data according to the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `foreach` as

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $hash = date('F', strtotime($value['comp_date']));
    if (isset($result[$hash])) {
        $result[$hash]['comp_month'] = $hash;
        $result[$hash]['lead'] = (isset($value['comp_status']) && $hash == $result[$hash]['comp_month'] && $value['comp_status'] == 'Lead') ? $result[$hash]['lead'] + 1 : $result[$hash]['lead'];
        $result[$hash]['opportunity'] = (isset($value['comp_status']) && $hash == $result[$hash]['comp_month'] && $value['comp_status'] == 'Opportunity') ? $result[$hash]['opportunity'] + 1 : $result[$hash]['opportunity'];
        $result[$hash]['conversion'] = (isset($value['comp_status']) && $hash == $result[$hash]['comp_month'] && $value['comp_status'] == 'Conversion') ? $result[$hash]['conversion'] + 1 : $result[$hash]['conversion'];
    } else {
        $result[$hash]['comp_month'] = date('F', strtotime($value['comp_date']));
        $result[$hash]['lead'] = ($value['comp_status'] == 'Lead') ? 1 : 0;
        $result[$hash]['opportunity'] = ($value['comp_status'] == 'Opportunity') ? 1 : 0;
        $result[$hash]['conversion'] = ($value['comp_status'] == 'Conversion') ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
uksort($result,function($a,$b){ return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);});
print_r(array_values($result));
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/423975)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `foreach()` + `array_walk()` version:

```
foreach($array as $key => $row) {
    $dateKey                =   date("Y-m",strtotime(str_replace('/',"-",$row['comp_date']).':00'));
    $new[$dateKey][]        =   strtolower($row['comp_status']);
    $count[$dateKey]        =   array_count_values($new[$dateKey]);
}

array_walk($count,function(&$count,$k) {
    $count['comp_date']     =   date("F",strtotime($k));
    $count['conversion']    =   (empty($count['conversion']))? '0':$count['conversion'];
    $count['lead']          =   (empty($count['lead']))? '0':$count['lead'];
    $count['opportunity']   =   (empty($count['opportunity']))? '0':$count['opportunity'];
    ksort($count);
});

ksort($count,SORT_NATURAL);
print_r(array_values($count));
```